# php null value confusion in switch statement

Tags: php

I have the following php code that gives me an unexpected result:

```
$foo = NULL;

switch($foo)
{
    case 0:
        print "What?!";
}
```

I'd expect the result to be nothing, but it matches case 0. The php manual says that NULL is a non-value, so how can it equal 0?

Comment: Read the comments on http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php and you'll see the potential issues with loose comparison and switch statements.

Comment: Because `var_dump(NULL==0);` prints `bool(true)` ;-)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The `switch` statement applies [loose comparison](http://php.net/manual/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose) which means that the following things are treated as equivalent to 0:

```
false
0
"0"
NULL
"any string"
""
```

Answer (score 7):

beacuse php is not type strict language

```
$foo = NULL;

if( isset( $foo ) ) {
    switch( $foo ) {
        case 0:
            print "WTF!!!";
    }
}
```

Comment: It took me a second or two to realize why there's a case in an if statement.

Answer (score 5):

This can be also written like

```
$foo = NULL;

switch( true )
{
    case ( 0 === $foo ):
        print "What?!";
    default:
        print "Default?!";
}
```

Comment: At this point it would just be quicker to do an `if` on the comparison and an `else` on the default… ;D

Comment: At exactly this point a simple `if` would suffice an be even more explicit, but for I upvote this answer because it deals with strict comparison in switch-case **the proper way**.

Comment: It also allows the author to extrapolate this methodology for more complex solutions.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is doing a type-coerced, weak comparison. You will need to do this instead:

```
$foo = NULL;
if ($foo === 0)
    print "WTF!!!";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do what I did - it's lazy but it works.
Before running the switch, I checked if the value is null and, if so, changed it to something known:

```
IF ($foo==null) {
     $foo == 99;
}
switch($foo)
{
    case 99:
        print "This is NULL"; break;
    case 0:
        print "What?!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here, but it could be that the `switch` statement coerces the value of `$foo` when comparing to `0`. To test this hypothesis, why don't you try adding this above the switch statement:

```
echo $foo == NULL;
```

This should echo 1 before the curse, if I'm correct...

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The inaccuracy is with my testing, and it was pointed out to me. Check the comments, if you are interested.

From what I've tested, the top answer is inaccurate.
It seems as though a PHP `switch` statement sees NULL as a "joker", and applies any case to it.
I tried with different numbers and with a string, and they all fired. Nothing there suggests it should be NULL, not even on PHP loose comparison.
So my suggestion is adding a `case NULL:` at the start, just as you add `default` at the end.

```
    $foo = NULL;

    switch($foo)
    {
        case NULL:
            print "This is NULL"; break;
        case 0:
            print "What?!";
    }
```

Comment: Your code shows that you miss break statement. That means the first matching `case` fell through all the following `case`s, which lead you to wrong conclusion that `null` is a "joker". It is not. As stated in accepted answer, this is the case of loose comparison. See https://3v4l.org/TY4DP as a proof.

Comment: @EduardSukharev I see what you mean. The first case accepted it, and so it all cases following it without a `break` were accepted as well.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As of PHP 8, you can use the [`match`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.match.php) expression:

> The match expression branches evaluation based on an identity check of a value.
>
> Similarly to a switch statement, a match expression has a subject expression that is compared against multiple alternatives.
>
> Unlike switch, it will evaluate to a value much like ternary expressions. Unlike switch, the comparison is an identity check (===) rather than a weak equality check (==).
>
> Match expressions are available as of PHP 8.0.0.

Per your example:

```
$foo = null;

$value = match($foo) {
    0 => print('What?')
};
```

Will output:

> Fatal error: Uncaught UnhandledMatchError: Unhandled match value of type null

So you can add a `try/catch` and handle it accordingly or add a `default` "catch-all":

```
$compare = null;

$value = match($compare) {
    0 => print('What?'),
    default => print('Default!')
};
```